# mapDispatchToProps error: component is receiving an object but function expected

Tags: redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

I am completely new to the react ecosystem. To get a better understanding of react saga I created a small project which displays a value on the screen and after 5 seconds it is a saga function is supposed be calle from useEffect and change that value. I have put some log message in saga and action functions. It seems that the listener is not being called.

**constants.js**

```
export const ATTEMPT_DELAY = 'app/SupportPage/ATTEMPT_DELAY';
export const DELAY_SUCCESS = 'app/SupportPage/DELAY_SUCCESS';
export const DELAY_ERROR = 'app/SupportPage/DELAY_SUCCESS';
```

**action.js**

```
import { ATTEMPT_DELAY, DELAY_SUCCESS, DELAY_ERROR } from './constants';

export function attempDelay() {
  console.log('attempt delay action called');
  return {
    type: ATTEMPT_DELAY,
  };
}

export function delaySuccess(value) {
  console.log('delay success action called');
  return {
    type: DELAY_SUCCESS,
    value,
  };
}

export function delayError() {
  return {
    type: DELAY_ERROR,
  };
}
```

**saga.js**

```
import { takeLatest, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { ATTEMPT_DELAY } from './constants';
import { delaySuccess, delayError } from './actions';

export function* delayListener() {
  yield takeLatest(ATTEMPT_DELAY, delay);
}

export function* delay() {
  console.log('delay saga called')
  const value = 10;
  try {
    yield put(delaySuccess(value));
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(delayError);
  }
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import produce from 'immer';
import { ATTEMPT_DELAY, DELAY_SUCCESS, DELAY_ERROR } from './constants';

export const initialState = {
  value: 5,
  isLoading: false,
};

const supportPageReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  produce(state, draft => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
    switch (action.type) {
      case ATTEMPT_DELAY:
        draft.isLoading = true;
        break;
      case DELAY_SUCCESS:
        draft.value = action.value || console.log('setting value');
        break;
      case DELAY_ERROR:
        draft.isLoading = false;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

export default supportPageReducer;
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { memo, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { compose } from 'redux';

import { useInjectSaga } from 'utils/injectSaga';
import { useInjectReducer } from 'utils/injectReducer';
import makeSelectSupportPage from './selectors';
import reducer from './reducer';
import { delayListener } from './saga';
import { attempDelay } from './actions';
import messages from './messages';

export function SupportPage({ supportPage: { isLoading, value }, delay }) {
  useInjectReducer({ key: 'supportPage', reducer });
  useInjectSaga({ key: 'supportPage', saga: delayListener });

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('delay called');
      delay();
    }, 5000);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>SupportPage</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Description of SupportPage" />
      </Helmet>
      <FormattedMessage {...messages.header} />
      <h1>{isLoading ? 'loading' : 'not loading'}</h1>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

SupportPage.propTypes = {
  supportPage: PropTypes.object,
  delay: PropTypes.func,
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  supportPage: makeSelectSupportPage(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    delay: dispatch(attempDelay()),
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default compose(
  withConnect,
  memo,
)(SupportPage);
```

when I open the console in the browser I see the log before calling calling delay() from useEffect and there is an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: delay is not defined
at eval" I tried googling this error but not get anything relevant to redux-saga.
I noticed something when after running the project when I make a change and hit save it rebuilds the project and then the saga gets called and all the log messages are there and the value changed as it supposed to.
I don't know what is going on!!!

Comment: Not related to redux-saga. Currently `delay` in `SupportPage` component is not extracted from props and is not defined - hence the error

Comment: BTW, composing connect and memo is redundant (connect "memos" on its own)

Comment: I did not write the composing react-boilerplate did that

Comment: I edited the question to extract delay, but then It says delay is not a fucntion

Comment: Are you sure you're rendering the connected component? Why SupportPage function is exported?

Comment: Yes I am sure I am rendering it. I think the issue is how I am getting the dispatch as props, but I don't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    delay: dispatch(attempDelay()),
  };
}
```

here I am calling dispatch and mapping the return value of dispatch to delay which is an object. It is supposed to be a function.

the correction will be:

```
delay: () => dispatch(attempDelay()),
```

Comment: Or simply `delay: attempDelay,`

Comment: that won't invoke any listener saga, we need to dispatch actions to hit saga middlewares

Comment: really. I didn't know that. I will try it out. thank you

Comment: Just to clarify: `const mapDispatchToProps = { delay: attempDelay, }`